# Java calling values from other method

Tags: java, variables

I am pretty new to Java. I get the error "cannot find symbol - variable aw" when I try to call a value from another method.

What should I do?

My Code

```
public class Monster {

    private int angriffswert;
    private int lebenspunkte;


    public Monster(){
        angriffswert(aw);
    }

    public int angriffswert(int aw) {
       angriffswert = 6;
       aw = angriffswert;
       return aw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, you need to learn about variable scope.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just want to call the aw, where the value is "6" from the method angriffswert() in the method public Monster()

Comment: 'Calling values' is already meaningless. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to look into [variable scope](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables)

```
private int angriffswert;
private int lebenspunkte;
```

These are instance variables and can be accessed by any method in the class.
In the `angriffswert(int aw)` method you access the `angriffswert` instance variable.

In the initializer you are calling the `angriffswert` method and pass it `aw`, but `aw` is not defined in either the initializer or as an instance variable. So you can either do the following;

```
{
  int aw = 0;
  angriffswert(aw);
}
```

or

```
private int aw = 0;
{
  angriffswert(aw);
}
```

You could also just call the `angriffswert` method and pass an int value and not an int variable; `angriffswert(0)`